# Aligning matrices across examples

Tags: beamer, align, matrices

How can I align the two identical blocks in the following (the blocks consisting of rows with words in)?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,color, graphicx, amsfonts, braket}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{exe}
    \ex
\[
\begin{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
Semantic\;type:\\ 
\texttt{expression}:\\ 
Semantic\; term:\\
\end{matrix}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{matrix}
e\\
 \text{John}\\
 \operatorname{j}\\
\end{matrix}
\end{matrix}
\]

\ex
\[
\begin{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
Semantic\;type:\\ 
\texttt{expression}:\\ 
Semantic\; term:\\
\end{matrix}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{matrix}
\cfrac{\ \operatorname{t}\ }{\ e\ }\\ 
\texttt{every linguist}\\ 
\cfrac{\ \operatorname{ev.ling(\lambda x.[\;])}\ }{\ x\ }\\
\end{matrix}
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{exe}


\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `empheq` already loads `mathtools`, which in turn loads `amsmath`. `beamer` automatically loads `amssymb` (and thus `amsfonts`) as well as `color` and `graphicx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution forces beamer to use `leqn` equations and uses `\mathmakebox` to center the aligned matrices.  The 4cm width is adjustable to taste.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\makeatletter
\tagsleft@true
\makeatother
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
\begin{matrix}
Semantic\;type:\\ 
\texttt{expression}:\\ 
Semantic\; term:\\
\end{matrix}
&\mathmakebox[4cm]{\begin{matrix}
e\\
 \text{John}\\
 \operatorname{j}\\
\end{matrix}}
\\
\begin{matrix}
Semantic\;type:\\ 
\texttt{expression}:\\ 
Semantic\; term:\\
\end{matrix}
&
\mathmakebox[4cm]{\begin{matrix}
\cfrac{\ \operatorname{t}\ }{\ e\ }\\ 
\texttt{every linguist}\\ 
\cfrac{\ \operatorname{ev.ling(\lambda x.[\;])}\ }{\ x\ }\\
\end{matrix}}
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: beamer slide]

Answer (score 1):

like this:

[image]

with using only tabular:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{empheq,
            nccmath} % for \mfrac
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%[fragile]
    \begin{exe}%\raggedright
    \ex
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.45\linewidth}
                   @{\qquad}
                   >{$}l<{$}
              }
Semantic type:          &   e           \\
\texttt{expression:}    &   $John$      \\
Semantic term:          &   \mathsf{j}

\end{tabular}

    \ex
\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.45\linewidth}
                   @{\qquad}
                   >{$}l<{$}
              }
Semantic type:          &   \mfrac{\ \mathsf{t}\ }{e}   \\
\texttt{expression:}    &   $\texttt{every linguist}$   \\
Semantic term:          &   \mfrac{\ \mathsf{ev.ling}(\lambda x.[~])\ }
                                  {x}

\end{tabular}
    \end{exe}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**edit:** from your comment can be gues that you like to have something like this:

[image]

difference to the first solution is in removed position option `[t]` and reduced size of the first column in tables. also in increased vertical space between `\ex` (examples).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{empheq,
            nccmath} % for \mfrac
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%[fragile]
    \begin{exe}%\raggedright
    \ex
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.3\linewidth}
                   @{\qquad}
                   >{$}l<{$}
              }
Semantic type:          &   e           \\
\texttt{expression:}    &   $John$      \\
Semantic term:          &   \mathsf{j}

\end{tabular}
\bigskip

    \ex
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.3\linewidth}
                   @{\qquad}
                   >{$}l<{$}
              }
Semantic type:          &   \mfrac{\ \mathsf{t}\ }{e}   \\
\texttt{expression:}    &   $\texttt{every linguist}$   \\
Semantic term:          &   \mfrac{\ \mathsf{ev.ling}(\lambda x.[~])\ }
                                  {x}

\end{tabular}
    \end{exe}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Thanks. There are two issues with this, though. First, the blocks are too far away from the numbers (1) and (2). Second, the aligning of the blocks is not as in my examples, in which the top row and the bottom row are at the middle of the word in the middle row.

Comment: @user65526, your question is not clear. please clarify it with some sketch, what you like to have. so far we can only guess what should be align. you can make first column of `tabula` narrower if you like to have column context closer to `qex` number.